How can I compress text in Python to only use certain characters?
How can I compress text in Python but the output string only contains upper and lowercase letters, numbers, "." (dot), and "_" (underscore).
Here is an example of something that would work but the output does not contain any lowercase letters or dots so the compression would be less efficient.
import base64
import zlib

def compress(s):
  return base64.b32encode(zlib.compress(s,level=9)).decode("ascii").replace("=","-")
print(compress(b"abc"))


I think a possible solution would be to convert to base64 and then convert each number to one of the allowed characters in the output

You don't need the trailing equal signs. Remove them, and then add them back on the decoding end based on the length of the encoded data. Also the base64 methods have an option to specify the last two characters to use instead of + and /.
To encode:
enc = base64.b64encode(dat, b'._').rstrip(b'=')

To decode:
dat = base64.b64decode(enc + b'=' * (-len(enc) & 3), b'._')


Note: I found that for Python's b64decode(), you don't need to append the correct number of equal signs (at least in version 3.9.4). It turns out that you can simply always append two equal signs, and it will work. However, this is arguably a bug in b64decode(), so the behavior should not be depended on.

Why don't you try base64? I rewrite the code to the following:
import base64
import zlib

def compress_64(s):
    return base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(s, level=9)).decode("ascii").replace(
        "=", "-")

print(compress_64(b"abc"))

The output is eNpLTEoGAAJNASc-, much shorter and contains more characters compared with the former one's output, which is PDNEWTCKAYAAETIBE4------
However, both base32 and base64 were not designed for compress - it often occupy more spaces after encode.

I understand that the output might be larger than the input since the input can contain any characters but the output can only contain certain characters

I don't think that would work since base64 encoding in Python uses 65 characters: upper and lowercase letters, numbers, "+", "=", "/"

"it often occupy more space" -- for any non-empty input, Base64 will require more space, since it needs 4 bytes to encode each 3 input bytes. | "base64 encoding in Python uses 65 characters" -- it uses 64 symbols, hence the name.

@DanMašek No, it uses 65. Base64 appends zero to two equal signs. Sometimes new lines are thrown in as well (not in Python though), making it 66 characters. And maybe even carriage returns, making it 67!

@MarkAdler OK. I was thinking of the symbols that encode some information. CR/LF certainly don't, and even the equal signs are strictly not necessary.

Final code based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/78468531/13156064
import base64
import zlib

class TextEncoder:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def encode(self,dat):
        return base64.b64encode(dat, b'._').rstrip(b'=')
    def decode(self,enc):
        return base64.b64decode(enc + b'=' * (-len(enc) & 3), b'._')
    def encode_and_compress(self,dat):
        return self.encode(zlib.compress(dat,level=9))
    def decode_and_decompress(self,enc):
        return zlib.decompress(self.decode(enc))

